# How to compute wavenumber from FFT data using FFTW library?

Tags: c, fft, fftw

I am using a gray-scale infrared camera. I get pixel data from the IR camera, and then I convert this pixel data into integer. After I get Integer values, I normalize the data:

```
normalized[j] = static_cast<double>(GrayData[j]-min_value)/(max_value-min_value);
inputdata_fft[j] = static_cast<double>(normalized[j]);
```

Is it good to normalize data?
After that, I do FFT using FFTW library. My code is as follows:

```
Complex_data_out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*(buffer_size/2+1));
magnitude_fft_num = (double *) malloc(buffer_size*sizeof(double));
fft_for_proc = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(buffer_size, inputdata_fft, Complex_data_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(fft_for_proc);
for(int i=0; i<static_cast<int>(buffer_size/2); i++)
{
    real = Complex_data_out[i][0];  //Extract real component
    imag = Complex_data_out[i][1];   //Extract imaginary component
    magnitude_fft_num[i] = sqrt((real*real)+(imag*imag));  // Calculate the Magnitude
    data_out_fft[i] = static_cast<int>(magnitude_fft_num[i]);
}
```

Now I have FFT data. How can i compute wavenumber from this data? I want to plot wavenumber (per cm) on x-axis and intensity on y-axis. How to get intensity values? I also found the following way to calculate wavenumber:

```
data_out_fft[i] = static_cast<int>(magnitude_fft_num[i]*2*pii);
```

Is this correct? Please help me. Thanks